# How to perform OR text search on nested documents in Solr

Tags: solr, nested

I have indexed a nested document structure in Solr 8.5.1 like this:

```
"docs": [
    {
        "id": "unmatching_parent_and_children",
        "searchtext": "bla bla bla",
        "entity_type": "parent",
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_and_children.child_1",
                "searchtext": "bla bla",
                "entity_type": "child_type_1"
            },
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_and_children.child_2",
                "searchtext": "bla bla bla",
                "entity_type": "child_type_2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "matching_parent_unmatching_children",
        "searchtext": "bla searchterm bla bla",
        "entity_type": "parent",
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "matching_parent_unmatching_children.child_1",
                "searchtext": "bla bla",
                "entity_type": "child_type_1"
            },
            {
                "id": "matching_parent_unmatching_children.child_2",
                "searchtext": "bla bla bla",
                "entity_type": "child_type_2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_1",
        "searchtext": "bla bla bla",
        "entity_type": "parent",
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_1.child_1",
                "searchtext": "bla searchterm bla",
                "entity_type": "child_type_1"
            },
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_1.child_2",
                "searchtext": "bla bla bla",
                "entity_type": "child_type_2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_2",
        "searchtext": "bla bla bla",
        "entity_type": "parent",
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_2.child_1",
                "searchtext": "bla bla",
                "entity_type": "child_type_1"
            },
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_2.child_2",
                "searchtext": "bla bla searchterm bla",
                "entity_type": "child_type_2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am looking for a query that performs a text search on `searchtext` in all parent and child documents, and that matches parents with a matching `searchtext` OR parents with children with a matching `searchtext`, or parents and children both with matching `searchtext`.

Something like this (this is pseudo code):

```
q=(entity_type:parent AND searchtext:searchterm) 
    OR ({!parent which="entity_type:parent"}(-entity_type:parent AND +searchtext:searchterm))
fl=id,[child parentFilter="entity_type:parent"]
```

Expected result:

```
"docs": [
    {
        "id": "matching_parent_unmatching_children",
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "matching_parent_unmatching_children.child_1",
            },
            {
                "id": "matching_parent_unmatching_children.child_2",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_1",
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_1.child_1",
            },
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_1.child_2",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_2",
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_2.child_1",
            },
            {
                "id": "unmatching_parent_matching_child_2.child_2",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So far, I had no success constructing a Solr query that meets this requirement. Either the query generates parsing errors, or
it is interpreted as a plain search text without honoring the expressions within, or only document structures are matched in
which both parent AND children have a matching `searchtext`. The Query Parsers I experimented with (in several combinations) are Lucene, eDisMax/DisMax, Block Join Parent and Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query with my own dataset and got some parsing erros too:

```
"Parent query must not match any docs besides parent filter. Combine them as must (+) and must-not (-) clauses to find a problem doc. docID=0"
```

I don't understand why this parsing error occurs.

But it works for me when I moved the sub-query **-entity_type:parent AND +searchtext:searchterm** into the **filters** parameter of the {!parent} query:

```
q=(entity_type:parent AND searchtext:searchterm) OR ({!parent which="entity_type:parent" filters="-entity_type:parent AND +searchtext:searchterm"})

fl=id,[child parentFilter="entity_type:parent"]
```

It should return the same result. See also https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/other-parsers.html#filtering-and-tagging-2

I hope this will help you too.

Comment: I think filters do not affect scoring, as far as I understood. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-Thefq_FilterQuery_Parameter. Unsure if this is good or bad.

Comment: The parsing error you mention occurs if the parent query matches not only parent docs, but also potential children.

Comment: Are you using edismax/dismax instead of the lucene Query Parser? If I do that, and activate debugQuery, the result is: `"parsedquery_toString":"+(entity_type:parent (searchtext:and) searchtext:searchterm (searchtext:or) (searchtext:parent) (searchtext:which) (searchtext:entity_type:parent) (searchtext:entity_type:parent) (searchtext:and) +searchtext:searchterm)"`. This means, it searches for the keywords "and", "which", "parent" etc. instead of interpreting them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parent block join query parser like this. I have used your data and schmea and it is working fine as expected

```
q=(searchtext:searchterm AND entity_type:parent) OR _query_: "{!parent which=entity_type:parent}+searchtext:searchterm"

fl=id,[child parentFilter="entity_type:parent"]
```